# What exactly does ppoints() in R do?

Tags: r

The `ppoints()` function is simple but very mysterious to me. It seems to throw away the input vector. What exactly is it doing? The documentation simply mentions what the function calculates, but doesn't explain the formula used. The references provided in the documentation are not easily accessible.

```
function (n, a = if (n <= 10) 3/8 else 1/2) 
{
if (length(n) > 1L) 
    n <- length(n)
if (n > 0) 
    (1L:n - a)/(n + 1 - 2 * a)
else numeric()
}
```

Comment: Search for "probability plotting points."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you $n$ equally spaced points between $0$ and $1$, at least when $a \le 1$.

For $n>10$ the default use of $a=\frac12$ puts the first point at $\frac1{2n}$ and the last at $\frac{2n-1}{2n}$.

For $n\le 10$ the default use of the smaller $a=\frac38$ bring the points together slightly slightly more, with the first at  $\frac5{8n+2}$ and the last at $\frac{8n-3}{8n+2}$.

It is sensible to have $a$ between $0$ and $1$: here are three examples

```
ppoints(10, a=1/2) # ten equally-spaced points from 1/20 to 19/20 
#  0.05 0.15 0.25 0.35 0.45 0.55 0.65 0.75 0.85 0.95
ppoints(9,  a=0)   # nine equally-spaced points from 1/10 to 9/10
# 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9
ppoints(11, a=1)   # eleven equally-spaced points from 0 to 1
#  0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

For large $n$ (which is how usually I use it) it probably does not matter much and the effect of $a=\frac12$ is easier to explain.

For small $n$ it may matter more, and is related to the `quantile()` function with the selection of $\frac38$ here being related to `type=9` there. Apparently this leads to getting closer to the expected value of the order statistics from a normal distribution so `qnorm(ppoints(4))` gives `-1.0491314 -0.2993069  0.2993069  1.0491314` while `qnorm(ppoints(4,1/2))` gives `-1.1503494 -0.3186394  0.3186394  1.1503494` and the former is closer to the desired values of $\mathbb E[X_{(1)}]\approx -1.029$, $\mathbb E[X_{(2)}]\approx -0.297$ etc.  Whether this point matters to you is a matter for you and you can always change `a` if you wish.

Comment: I understand how the function works, but why exactly is it using a=1/2 and 3/8? Why does n being less than or more than 10 matter?

Comment: @Prometheus I have added to my answer on this point.  There is a reason, which may or may not appeal to you.